# R Arimax Function

Tags: r, time-series, arima, arma

I want to make forecast on my data by running an arimax model.
The data is like:

```
Value1, Flag1, Flag2, ................., FlagN    
Value2, Flag1, Flag2, ................., FlagN    
Value3, Flag1, Flag2, ................., FlagN    
Value4, Flag1, Flag2, ................., FlagN    
Value5, Flag1, Flag2, ................., FlagN    
....    
ValueM, Flag1, Flag2, ................., FlagN
```

So, when I want to make a new forecast, I will provide flag values to the model, then it can give me the forecast value?

How can I prepare the input data?
What is the proper R function and proper way of calling?

Answer (score 1):

You want the `arima` function in base R, or the `Arima` function in the forecast package.  `auto.arima` may be useful as well.

type `?arima` into R to read the help page, which gives a good overview for fitting such models.  You'll want to split your data into 2 parts: a vector of class `ts` for "value," and a matrix of your external regressors, which you pass to the `xreg` argument of the various arima functions.

You can then predict these models using the `predict` function. You will need to make forecasts of your xregs and pass them to the prediction function in the `newxreg` argument.  You can also use the `forecast` function in the forecast package to produce confidence intervals and plots.  `?predict.Arima` in base R and `?forecast.Arima` in forecast.

Before you do any of this; however, you need to think about your forecasting problem.  Say you want to forecast 1 step ahead (for ValueN).  Will you have the flags for ValueN at time M?  If not, your ARIMAX model will be useless.